# Convert C# List<int[]> to JavaScript using Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

how can I convert a list of integer arrays from C# to JavaScript? Is there a way to parse it? I've tried something along these lines:

```
@List<int[]> linkedRazorResources = Model.LinkedEvents;
for(var i = 0; i<@linkedRazorResources.Count;i++){
  linkedResources[i] = @linkedRazorResources[i];
}
```

I can't seem to access the index in `@linkedRazorResources[i]` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Html.Raw` and `Json.Encode` methods in your `.cshtml`:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var linkedRazorResourcesForJs = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(linkedRazorResources));
 </script>
```

The you can use this variable in your .js files.

`Json.Encode` converts a data object to a string that is in the JSON. And after that `Html.Raw` returns markup that is not HTML encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Try a JSON Encode:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(linkedRazorResources))
```

This will output the raw JavaScript Object, and you can use this directly inside your JavaScript `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below,

```
 <script type="text/jscript">
   var jsonVariable =      @(Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(linkedRazorResources)));//using Newtonsoft
  //or you can use below
  //var jsonVariable = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(linkedRazorResources))
  </script>
```